# .htaccess redirect ?_escaped_fragment_=

Tags: php, .htaccess

I understand google will fetch this url and make a request to the server in this form:

```
http://test1.ru/compare/search.php?r=ade$da1A$ade$da2A$ade$da3A#!hash1.html
compare.test1.ru/search.php?r=ade$da1A$ade$da2A$ade$da3A#!hash1.html

http://test1.ru/compare/search.php?r=ade$da1A$ade$da2A$ade$da3A?_escaped_fragment_=hash1.html
compare.test1.ru/search.php?r=ade$da1A$ade$da2A$ade$da3A?_escaped_fragment_=hash1.html
```

server path to html `http://test1.ru/hash/hash1.html` (hash/hash1.html)

needed redirect form

```
http://test1.ru/hash/hash1.html
compare.test1.ru/hash/hash1.html
```

without change url - `compare.test1.ru/search.php?r=ade$da1A$ade$da2A$ade$da3A#!hash1.html`

thank you

Comment: I'd ditch hashbangs (they are a horrible hack and the performance penalty of loading the initial page and then Ajax loading the replacement page can be nasty). Use [the history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) instead,  like [github do](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#!hash1.html` *is never sent to the server*, therefore, there's nothing you can do on the server's end, in php, or using your htaccess file, to parse out the URL fragment. You're only going to be able to do this on the browser's end, using something like javascript.

Comment: is in .htaccess

there are about a short address but as it is on the right

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /hash/%1 [NC,L]

http://test1.ru/?_escaped_fragment_=hash1.html - OK!
http://test1.ru/compare/search.php?r=ade$da1A$ade$da2A$ade$da3A?_escaped_fragment_=hash1.html - NO! ):